# how to get files from iOS device or external device in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, loading

How to get text files or pdf files from local device or else external device(memory card) in iOS? It will be helpful if you can give some sample or tutorial.

Comment: Seeing how this question is likely to be closed here is some advice for when you re-post: try something first & pound out some code. when you get stuck or hit a snag as a question about that snag. Don't submit a question like, "can someone write my app for me" which is essentially what you have done here. good luck.

Comment: It was downvoted because you didn't ask a development question - you asked the community to give you code for your entire project. If you want tutorials I would suggest using Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dropbox. Place the files in a Dropbox folder and then with the iOS free Dropbox app, you can view the files in your iPhone/iPad.

Comment: I'm new to iOS development.Please let me know how to get  dropbox files from ipad app?

Comment: What do you want specifically? View the files as a user or get the files inside an application you are developing?

Comment: Actually I want to get files when a button clicked event.

Comment: The you have to use the Dropbox API for iOS in your app. Google for Dropbox iOS API.